# How to load another View when loading a ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` it has 3 views. What I want to do is without loading the default view when loading the `ViewController`, load other view of the same `ViewController` (rarther than load the main view) 
IS this possible. Then how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: try this in viewDidLoad: [self.view addSubView:self.view] I think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call the `addSubView` method of the UIView class.

So, when your initial view loads in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController`, you add another sub view to it.

`[self.view addSubView : YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_HERE];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more precise description of your problem.As when you talk about a view, it can be a view like UIButton  which can be added like

[Self.view addsubview:yourView];

But if you have created that view in some other custom class which is subclass of UIView ,then in your  viewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    obj =[[customView alloc] init];
    self.view =obj;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

Where customView is a subclass of UIView whose view you wan't to load, not the view of the original viewController file.
What you are doing over here is that when the viewDidLoad method is called , you change the view of that viewController to  view of the customView (subclass of UIView).
(adding view as  addSubview is best option I think)